# How to make concatenations at const wchar_t* parameters?

Tags: c++, string, gdi+

How to make concatenations at **`const wchar_t*`** parameter in this case?

I'm trying to make screenshots that are saved automatically with names like:

```
screen-1.jpg
screen-2.jpg
screen-3.jpg
...
screen-i.jpg`
```

Code:

```
p_bmp->Save(L"C:/Users/PCUSER/AppData/screen-" + filenumber + ".jpg", &pngClsid, NULL);
 //filenumber is ant int that increases automatically
```

But it's giving me an error:

> ```
> expression must have integral or unscoped
> ```

Comment: use a [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw C-style string pointers (like `const wchar_t*`) cannot be concatenated together with a string semantic using `operator+`. However, you can concatenate instances of **C++ string classes**, like ATL `CString` or `std::wstring`, just to name a few.

Since you have also *integer* values to concatenate, you can first convert these to string objects (e.g using `std::to_wstring()`), and then use the overloaded `operator`+ to concatenate the various strings.

```
#include <string> // for std::wstring and to_wstring()
...

// Build the file name string using the std::wstring class
std::wstring filename = L"C:/Users/PCUSER/AppData/screen-";
filename += std::to_wstring(filenumber); // from integer to wstring
filename += L".jpg";

p_bmp->Save(filename.c_str(), // convert from wstring to const wchar_t*
            &pngClsid, 
            NULL);
```

---

Another approach you may follow if you use the ATL `CString` class is formatting the result string in a way similar to `printf()`, invoking the `CString::Format()` method, e.g.:

```
CStringW filename;
filename.Format(L"C:/Users/PCUSER/AppData/screen-%d.jpg", filenumber);

p_bmp->Save(filename, // implicit conversion from CStringW to const wchar_t*
            &pngClsid, 
            NULL);
```